# Embedded Database Login System (netbeans java)

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, authentication, embedded-database

Alright, so i'm **working on a database** where **the only criteria to login is a password.** The database is to be only run from one computer in an offline state (Local) I read around and it pointed me in the direction of creating an embedded database. **I believe im working with derby in Netbeans using Java**.

My table consists of a primary key as an account number, name and password.

**I'm trying to**: Compare inputted password with a "password" column in a table(Users) within the database, so Table = various user info + password column

**My problem**: It throws some errors when i try to access the database to compare the inputted password (That was in the passwordField) to the database password.

**Errors**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at MainApplication.Login.loginButtMouseClicked(Login.java:112)
at MainApplication.Login.access$000(Login.java:7)
at MainApplication.Login$1.mouseClicked(Login.java:37)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6528)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4542)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

**Here is my connection Helper class**

```
package MainApplication;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class DBConnect {

    public static Connection Connect() {
        Connection conn;

        try {
        String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/USERS";
        String uName = "test";
        String uPass = "test";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Database Connected");
        return conn;
        }

        catch (SQLException err){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null ,err);
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

**And this is my Login Base code without swing components**

```
package MainApplication;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    Connection conn;
    PreparedStatement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;

//Initializer
    public Login() {
        initComponents();
        DBConnect.Connect();
    }
```

**Login Button**

```
    private void loginButtMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
    String pass = passText.getText();
    try {
        stmt = (PreparedStatement) conn.createStatement();
        String SQL = "select * from users where password  ='" + pass + "'";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
        if (rs.next()){
            int id = rs.getInt("ACCOUNTNUMBER");
            String firstName = rs.getString("firstName");
            String lastName = rs.getString("lastName");
            String accInfo = id + " " + firstName + ", " + lastName;
            System.out.println(accInfo);
        }    
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Side note: I read that hashing or salting would probably be a good idea for security... but I would probably have to be able to connect before implementing it? Also heard that using a prepared statement is more secured which is why that's there.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: `at MainApplication.Login.loginButtMouseClicked(Login.java:112)` what is the line 112 here?

Comment: 112            stmt = (PreparedStatement) conn.createStatement();

I've also tried just regular statement and changed the declaration to a regular statement. *Sometimes the program runs infinitely/for a long time without throwing an error*